# Visual Studio 2015 always publishing an old version of my application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Preview with ASP.NET MVC 6 to build a web application. The application works fine when previewed from within Visual Studio.

However, when I publish the application to a filesystem, it builds a very old version of the application and templates - in fact, it's from the first time I published to the filesystem. It's using the old Model, Controller, Templates, etc.

I've tried doing all of the following before publishing:

- Deleting all previous files from the destination directory
- "Clean Solution"
- "Clean Project"
- "Rebuild Solution"
- "Rebuild Project"

Is there a cache somewhere I can delete to fix this problem?

Update: I have discovered that I can create an entirely new deploy profile and get a good publish for the first time I use that. That's not a long term solution though.

Comment: This 'old version' is about front end stuff (css, js, etc) or also server side code (controllers, models, etc) ?

Comment: Server side code - at the least it's using old Controllers, Models, Templates.

Comment: i know of no caches in place and didn't see that behavior on my own. Not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new deploy profile. Using the new profile, everything works fine, and has been working fine for months.

Answer (score 1):

Go to project.json and change the version from e.g. "1.0.0-*" to "1.0.1-*". After that, publish it again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. If I check this box (Delete all existing files prior to publish) it seems to use the newer versions. I know you said that in your original post, but if you were doing it manually instead of using this checkbox, maybe that is another answer?

I wonder if it has something to do with the assembly versioning? (or lack thereof, in my case)

[image: Delete all existing files prior to publish]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Publish -> Updates, check if Update location is empty in Application Updates.

[image: Application Updates]

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to go to the Project\xxx Properties...
and change it here.
[image: Part of the project Properties]